# Typescript create `nameOf` function compatible with TS environment

Tags: typescript

I'm using the following helper-function to get typesafe propertynames at runtime:

```
function nameOf<T>(name: Extract<keyof T, string>) { return name; }
```

Now this messes around with TS' capabilities of ensuring existing properties, as you can see e.g. here:

```
function fork<T extends Record<string, any>>(
    sources: T
): { [K in keyof T]: any } {
    return sources;
}

function nameOf<T>(name: Extract<keyof T, string>) { return name; }

class DemoObj {
    a?: string;
    b?: string;
}

let a = fork({
    a: 1,
    b: 2
});

//Works!
let aA = a.a;

let b = fork({
    [nameOf<DemoObj>('a')]: 1,
    [nameOf<DemoObj>('b')]: 2,
    //This should not be possible
    //[nameOf<DemoObj>('c')]: 2,
});

//This should not work!
let bB = b.x;
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOAnA1gHgCqIKYAeUeYAJgM6IBKeEapm5UqMYA5gDSICGYAngD4BACgBQiCYnJwQqCHnIAuRNlEBKZQG9EAbQDSiVonR4%20cYCoC6y3n0QBfRJvGTUeKLKTTZ88gG5Re1FRUEhYBEQwbgBbPAB5YBwRKNjlAFEiVG5oTBMzC2wuJhZ2ATUnRDcPVCQUvD8HYIgAG25ySgARPGi4OIAjACsnFwluAH5lYtY2AMlEPompZmmAoNFm9x5EAF5kNHRhZznuZQBGDhH55QAmQLUA0QB6R4B1ffIAQnXN7gBBHZ4ADpuA8NlB5gCUBhDpcdHUEpguj1%20gMRABybhotTWRDnWHwxJI3qDdF9LE464XObPbAACxglHItJkzVIkTg4L6eEQAAc4O0YH0NpdnnCYvFCd1iajhGiIOSbhd7PdgjT6YzmSBWezwQB3fZfMHzABCAL6gIIfiAA)

Can the `nameOf` helper function somehow be rewritten to keep typescript aware of the resulting type? And we're using this function in production for quite a while now without issues. But keeping minification etc. in mind, might this even be used? Works for me, but ...

Utilizing a *Typescript-native-way* it would be great to attach some use-cases, e.g. switch statements.

Comment: Your `nameOf` widens from the particular key to `keyof T`, and then computed properties get widened even further to index signatures (see [ms/TS#13948](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948)).  Probably you want `nameOf...("a")` to still be of type `"a"` after you're done and not `"a" | "b"`.  You could rewrite `nameOf` to do this but it needs to be called differently; for example, via currying like `nameOf<DemoObj>()("a")`.  Or you could (when TS4.9 lands) abandon `nameOf` in favor of the `satisfies` operator.  Both approaches shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/W4n7ON)

Comment: Does that fully address your question? If so I will write up a full answer explaining.  Otherwise what am I missing?

Comment: Super great answer, thank you so much! Sure, I'd mark it, if you write it down. You could maybe extend how a `switch`-statement could look like, utilizing `satisfies`.

Like:

`switch(prop) { case nameOf<obj>('a'): break; }` would look like, using the helper function.

Comment: "You could maybe extend how a `switch` statement..."  If you want that, could you [edit] the question to ask for it?  Comments can be removed, so it's important for anything you want to see answered to be in the question post itself.

Comment: Hey @jcalz, would you be so kind and check my question again? I've added the required information.

Comment: I guess I was expecting you to [edit] your code examples to include any use cases you care about, such as whatever `switch` statement you're talking about. If you set it up I might be able to answer, but I'm not inclined to make guesses about what you're looking for.  (And yeah if you want me to be notified then you should mention @jcalz in a comment; otherwise I won't notice that you've made an edit to the question)